# Issues with Netflix ICE

Tags: highcharts, netflix

There is a prerequisite to acquire the proper license of highstock before using the Netflix ICE. I do not want to invest any money into it, just want to explore the features of ICE.

**Do I have to buy a proper licence of highstock before using Netflix ICE?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test and try netflix ice OSS locally or for personal use then no, you don't need to spend cash as it is clearly mentioned on their site[http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts/#non-commercial] also.

But if you're using netflix ice commercially then you have to buy appropriate license from highcharts. It is more of a license usage question so may be you try reading about the license details highcharts is using, that weather the free version of highcharts can be used with the production environment of Netflix OSS project.